# datastracture arraylist string

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to calculate the average from Data column.

```
try {

    List<String>lines=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("crimerate.csv"));

    for (String line:lines){

        line=line.replace("\"","");
        String []result=line.split(",");

        double sum=0;
        double num =0;
        double close = Double.parseDouble(result[1]);
        sum+=close;
        num++;

        System.out.println(sum/num);

    }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

crimerate.csv

```
state    number    city

CA         12       LA

TX         20       DA

DC         24       DC

MN         10       MI
```

The outcome is *For input string: "number"* instead of 16.5. Can someone help me?

Comment: You do realize you are resetting your variables in your loop each time? After the edit, are you discarding the first line (which will not pass the `Double.parseDouble()` call).

Comment: Why are you replacing quotes and splitting on commas when neither of those characters are in the data you've shown?

Answer (score 0):

Move the accumulators outside of the loop; skip the first line. I am assuming the replace and split actually work based upon your input data. If not, then the `line.split` needs to be updated appropriately.

```
try {
    List<String>lines=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("crimerate.csv"));

    double sum = 0, num = 0; 
    for (String line:lines){
      //ignore first line
      if (num == 0) {
         ++num;
         continue;
      }

        line=line.replace("\"","");
        String []result=line.split(",");

        double close = Double.parseDouble(result[1]);
        sum+=close;
        num++;


        }// end of for-loop
         System.out.println(sum/num);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @vishalgajera, you are correct; I inadvertantly moved the `.println()` outside of the try block. Alternatively, the better approach would likely be to have both the declaration and `.println()` inside the try block. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @user6167014, glad it helped. I might humbly ask that you look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers